# Where can I add a conditional statement in this M function code (Power Query)?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to work my way through this PowerQuery problem but I'm getting fairly stumped (been throwing myself at it for hours).

The goal is to retrieve a value from a table, closest to a variable (x). Sample of the table:

| S | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1698 | 1737 | 1781 |
| 1 | 1737 | 1795 | 1855 |
| 2 | 1780 | 1854 | 1928 |
| 3 | 1822 | 1912 | 2002 |
| 4 | 1864 | 1971 | 2075 |
| 5 | 1907 | 2029 | 2149 |
| 6 | 1949 | 2086 | 2222 |
| 7 | 1992 | 2145 | 2296 |
| 8 | 2034 | 2203 | 2369 |
| 9 | 2077 | 2262 | 2443 |
| 10 | 2119 | 2320 | 2516 |
| 11 | 2162 | 2378 | 2590 |

Let's say the variable S = "1" (column name) and variable x is "2000". The code I'm using works fine in this scenario:

```
    let

    S = "1",
    x = 2000,
    Source = tblSchalen,
    Result = Table.Column(Source, S){List.Count(List.Select( Table.Column(Source, S), each _ <= x))}
in
    Result
```

This correctly returns the value of "2034", as 2000 is higher than 1992 and the closest (upstairs) neighbour is 2034.

The problem is that, if I make x "2500" it errors (too few elements in enumeration) since the search procedure sort of "overflows". I vaguely understand why this happens (it's counting the amount (List.Select) of values that are lower or equal to X, and uses that number that to return a row number?) but I'd like to prevent this overflow by inserting some conditional statements as I just would want every x variable above the highest value in the list to just return the highest value in the list. (so x = 2500 would return "2162" if S is 1, "2378" if S is 2 and "2516" if S is 3)

Could anyone help me in the right direction? The syntax in M is different enough from VBA to make me confused and the M editor isn't quite as helpful as the VBA editor when debugging.

edit:

I guess I "want something like this, but working", these conditional statements in M really trip me up, as the code below gives me a "Token Identifyer Expected" error:

```
    let
    S = "1",
    x = 2500,
    Source = tblSchalen,    
    amount = List.Count(List.Select(Table.Column(Source, S), each _ <= x)), // this return a number from 0 - 12
    if amount > 11 then amount = 11 else amount = amount
    Result = Table.Column(amount)
in
    Result
```

I've tried "Result = if amount > 11 etc etc" just to give it some identifier, but that's also no bueno.

Answer (score 0):

This would find the closest value to Table2 Column1 from Table1, using column name listed in Table2 Column2

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
TransformedTable1=Table.Buffer(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Table1, {"S"}, "Attribute", "Value")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Closest",(i)=>
Table.Sort(
    Table.AddColumn(Table.SelectRows(TransformedTable1,
    each [Attribute]=Text.From(i[Column2])),
   "diff", each Number.Abs([Value]-i[Column1]))
,{{"diff", Order.Ascending}})
{0}[Value]
)
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Note: Column 2 is the name of the column, not the position

Comment: did that work for you?